# Does $span{(1,0)^T} = \mathbb{R}^1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

As above, does $span\{(1,0)^T\} = \mathbb{R}^1$?

Or does $\mathbb{R}^1$ only contain vectors with one dimension?

Comment: The two spaces are [iso](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441758/what-does-isomorphic-mean-in-linear-algebra)[morphic](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1201900/what-is-an-isomorphism-linear-algebra).

Comment: Is $(1,0)^T$ in $\mathbb{R}^1$? The answer to your question is the same as the answer to this one.

Comment: The spaces are *isomorphic*, but not the same